# reinitialize/reallocate an object with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Im wondering if calling `[[MyClass alloc] init]` on an already existing (allocated) object create a leak in ARC? or does it manage the release and reallocation for you?

would doing the following be more proper:

```
myObject = nil;
myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

which is more appropriate? is there another way to do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ARC, you don't need to set the myObject to be nil before reallocating it,only this line of code will be fine:

```
myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

When xcode compiles the code, it will automatically add the right release mechanism in.